# error retrieving background image from BackgroundSubtractorMOG2

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the background image from BackgroundSubtractorMOG2:

```
bg->getBackgroundImage(back);
```

but I get a `Thread 1 SIGABRT` (which as a c++ n00b puzzles me)
and this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nchannels == 3) in getBackgroundImage, file /Users/hm/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.4/modules/video/src/bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp, line 579
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, suspecting it's something to do with the nmixtures paramater, but I've left that as the default(3). Any hints ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to use 3 channel images rather than grayscale. Make sure the image type you are using is CV_8UC3 or if you are reading from a file use `cv::imread('path/to/file')` with no additional arguments.

Comment: so can BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 only be used with 3 channel images ? I'm using 1 because it's a depth sensor stream

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I'm not really familiar with the method this class uses but it looks like this is the case given the assert. A popular method for foreground/background segmentation with grayscale images is to use [Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method) which is implemented in opencv as part of the [threshold function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=otsu#threshold).

Comment: Thanks Max, I've also checked Otsu thresholding, pretty neat!

Comment: For me, I have converted frame to 3 channel image first like this: Imgproc.CvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.ColorRgba2bgr);